# How do I display a countdown timer on a Angular Toaster

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-Idle(ngIdle) and Angular Toaster(toaster) modules. I want to display a toaster message on ng-idle's IdleWarn event with countdown value.

```
$scope.$on('IdleWarn', function(e, countdown) {
      console.log("Timeleft: " + countdown);
      toaster.warning('Title', '<section>' + countdown + '</section>', 0, 'trustedHtml', undefined, undefined, true, undefined, undefined);
    }
```

This only renders the toaster with a static countdown value. How do I implement a countdown timer to display counting-down with this toaster.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by editing the message property directly. Ensure you are using the latest version of angular-toaster (v.2.1.1 at time of writing).

```
var sessionToast;
$scope.toastr = // Injected via angularJS

$scope.$on('IdleWarn', function (e, countdown) {

if (sessionToast) {
    sessionToast.scope.message = countdown + ' seconds';
    sessionToast.scope.$digest();
}
else {
    sessionToast = self.toastr.warning(countdown + ' seconds', 'You will be logged out due to inactivity in:', {
        timeOut: 0,
        preventDuplicates: true,
        onHidden: () => {
            sessionToast = undefined;
        }
    });

}


});

$scope.$on('IdleEnd', function () {
    $scope.toastr.clear();
});

$scope.$on('IdleTimeout', function () {
    // do logout
    $scope.toastr.clear();
    // Maybe show a you have been logged out message.
});
```